# how to handle a signal

Tags: python, operating-system, signals

Given that when the below code runs as follows:

- `cli()` parses some configuration files
- `blabla()` prints a message "hi!"
- these 2 functions are the only ones in `main()`
- `cli()` is also the signal handler of `SIGUSR2`

Here is the snippet:

```
def cli():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--logger-file", dest="logger_file", required=True, help="YAML logging configuration file")
    parser.add_argument("--conf-file", dest="conf_file", required=True, help="app configuration file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    setup_logger(args.logger_file)
    commit_conf(args.conf_file)


def blabla():
    while True:
        logger.info("hi!")
        time.sleep(60)


def recv_sigusr2(signum, stack):
    cli()

def main():
    cli()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, recv_sigusr2)
    blabla()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The question is:

1. why `blabla()` runs every time that I am sending `SIGUSR2` signal, since only the signal handler makes a call to `cli()` only ?
2. how running only `cli()` can be achieved (without calling `blabla()`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) says about `time.sleep(secs)`:

> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. **The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep()** following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

So `blabla` is not called each time when SIGUSR2 is received, but another iteration of the loop starts immediately, because of `sleep` interruption.